# How to remove the Cookie from the browser whenever we press the Logout and as well as session destroyed?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jquery-mobile, spring-security

I have developed a mobile application using Jquery Mobile, Spring MVC and Spring Security.

Whenever I login to the application the Cookie is generated and stored in the browser.

Whenever I logout the application the session is destroyed, but the Cookie is there in the browser.

My Problem is that if Cookies are there in the browser the application is not running on an IPad running IOS 6.0.1.

How do I remove the cookie from the browser when I press Logout as well as destroy the session.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `delete-cookies` property in the logout handler for [session management.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-mgmt) I quote from the documentation:

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

You can specify more than one cooke with comas. But a warning also fro the documentation:

> Unfortunately this can't be guaranteed to work with every servlet
>   container, so you will need to test it in your environment

Also, take in account proxies:

> If you are running your application behind a proxy, you may also be
>   able to remove the session cookie by configuring the proxy server. For
>   example, using Apache HTTPD's mod_headers, the following directive
>   would delete the JSESSIONID cookie by expiring it in the response to a
>   logout request (assuming the application is deployed under the path
>   /tutorial):

```
 <LocationMatch "/tutorial/j_spring_security_logout">
  Header always set Set-Cookie "JSESSIONID=;Path=/tutorial;Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
 </LocationMatch>
```